# Join multi tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have some tables:

```
Function -- List of function
IDF(UK)
Title
Type

State -- List of possible authorization state
IDF(FK Function)
StateValue
StateDesc
Default

Folder -- List of containers
IDFolder
FolderName
Order

FolderDett -- List of Function in containers
IDFolder(FK Folder)
IDF(FK Function)
OrderInFolder

User -- User to authorize
IDUser(UK)
IDF(FK Function)
StateValue (FK State)

GroupUser -- Group of user to authorize
IDGroup
IDF(FK Function)
StateValue (FK State)
Priority
```

What I need is given a user (user group->I recover the user groups from another table) get a list of functions that the user can access("StateValue"), if the user has not specified a "StateValue" I must search for it in the "GroupUser" table (in case of multiple records select by priority why a user can be in different groups with different permissions) if even here I didn't find a value for "StateValue" I have to recover it from the State table (I select the row with the value 'Y' in the "Default" column) For the moment I wrote this query to put in list the functions ordered in the container, but the second part or add the StataValue and StateDesc for the user I have no idea how to do ... any ideas?

```
select t1.IDFolder,t2.IDF,Order,OrderInFolder,Title,Type from [Folder] t1
  JOIN [FolderDett] t2 ON t2.IDFolder = t1.IDFolder
  JOIN [Function] t3 ON t3.IDF = t2.IDF
  ORDER BY Order,OrderInFolder;
```

Example

```
Function
  IDF    | Title           | Type
  "Print"    "Print Order"     2
  "Transfer" "WS Transfer"     2
  "Change"   "Change"          3

  State
  IDF           | StateValue | Default
  "Print"           1           Y
  "Transfer"        1           Y
  "Change"          1           N
  "Print"           2           N
  "Transfer"        2           N
  "Change"          2           N
  "Print"           3           N
  "Transfer"        3           N
  "Change"          3           Y

  Folder
  IDFolder | FolderName | Order
  "F1"        "F1"         1

  FolderDett
  IDFolder | IDF        | OrderInFolder
  "F1"       "Print"       1
  "F1"       "Transfer"    2
  "F1"       "Change"      3

  User
  IDUser | IDF | StateValue
  "!"      "Print" 1

  GroupUser
  IDGroup | IDF | StateValue | Priority
  "Group1" "Transfer" 2         1


  output
  IDFolder | IDF   | Order | OrderInFolder |     Title     | Type | StateValue  | StateDesc
  "F1"     "Print"     1         1           "Print Order"   2       1          "Authorized"
  "F1"     "Transfer"  1         2           "WS Transfer"   2       2          "Read Only"
  "F1"     "Change"    1         3           "Change"        3       3          "Denied"
```

Comment: Add sample and expected output data.

Comment: I entered an example in the body of the question

Comment: You can use UNION to achieve this.

Comment: In the second select I have to make the join between State and User but if in User I can't find the StateValue how can I see in the UserGroup table and finally if even here there is not?

Answer (score 0):

This might help find the right StateValue.

```
select t1.IDFolder,t2.IDF,[Order],OrderInFolder,Title,[Type] ,
CASE WHEN u.StateValue IS NULL THEN
 CASE WHEN g.StateValue IS NULL THEN  s.StateValue ELSE g.StateValue  END
 ELSE u.StateValue
END StateValue,

(SELECT d.StateDesc FROM [State] d 
            WHERE d.IDF = t2.IDF  AND d.StateValue = CASE WHEN u.StateValue IS NULL THEN
                            CASE WHEN g.StateValue IS NULL THEN  s.StateValue ELSE g.StateValue  END
                            ELSE u.StateValue
                            END) StateDesc

from [Folder] t1
  JOIN [FolderDett] t2 ON t2.IDFolder = t1.IDFolder
  JOIN [Function] t3 ON t3.IDF = t2.IDF
  LEFT JOIN [User] u ON u.IDF = t2.IDF
  LEFT JOIN [GroupUser] g ON g.IDGroup =  (SELECT MIN(IDGroup) FROM [GroupUser] x WHERE x.IDF = t2.IDF)
  LEFT JOIN [State] s ON s.IDF = t2.IDF and ISNULL(s.[Default],'N') = 'Y'

  ORDER BY [Order],OrderInFolder
```

Comment: I try this statement on SQL Fiddle but I always get the incorrect syntax error